# Controlling a loop in Python

Tags: python

I am currently working on this code:

```
import time
import webbrowser

while True:
    user_inputq3 = raw_input("Which model of phone is it? ")  
    import csv  
    words=user_inputq3.split(" ")  
    reader=csv.reader(open("task3worksheet.csv"))  
    problemlist=[row for row in reader]  
    for x in range(0,len(words)):  
        for y in range(0,len(problemlist)-1,2):  
            if(words[x].lower() in problemlist[y]):  
                print(problemlist[y+1][0])  
                break  
            elif user_inputq3 == "exit":  
                print("The programme will now shut down.")  
                time.sleep(5)  
                exit(0)  
                break  
            else:  
                print("This troubleshooting programme will only support iPhone 3-7.")  
                print("Make sure you type in iphone then the model of iPhone. (e.g iphone4)")  
                print("If you do not have these versions of the iPhone, please type in exit when prompted with the question again.")  
                break
```

The "task3worksheet" is a excel worksheet which is full of keywords and a response. So for example when "iPhone4" is typed, "next question" should come up. However, when I type in "iPhone4", it says next question and loops back to the question again. How do I make it so that it doesn't move back to the question again, I want it so the current loop ends when the valid input is entered, so I can move on to other code.

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the help center's guidance on creating a [mcve]. In particular, a question's title should be specific to the individual problem, and the code should be the smallest possible thing that demonstrates the question or error -- with everything unrelated removed. StackOverflow isn't a forum but a Q&A site -- our goal is to create a database of canonical questions with answers that everyone can use; a question that isn't helpful to anyone but you doesn't work towards that goal.

Comment: You can just add a variable which tells you whether you've already printed any response. That should be easiest

Answer (score 0):

I added a variable that tells me if I already answered the question, if I did I break the outer loop.
Modified version for a suggestion in comment:

```
import time
import webbrowser

answered = False
while not answered:
    user_inputq3 = raw_input("Which model of phone is it? ")  
    import csv  
    words=user_inputq3.split(" ")  
    reader=csv.reader(open("task3worksheet.csv"))  
    problemlist=[row for row in reader]
    for x in range(0,len(words)):
        if answered:
            break
        for y in range(0,len(problemlist)-1,2):  
            if(words[x].lower() in problemlist[y]):  
                print(problemlist[y+1][0])  
                answered = True
                break
            elif user_inputq3 == "exit":  
                print("The programme will now shut down.")  
                time.sleep(5)  
                exit(0)  
                break  
            else:  
                print("This troubleshooting programme will only support iPhone 3-7.")  
                print("Make sure you type in iphone then the model of iPhone. (e.g iphone4)")  
                print("If you do not have these versions of the iPhone, please type in exit when prompted with the question again.")  
                break
```

Comment: This still loops back to the question "Which model of phone is it?", even after is recognises the correct input and the correct solution.

Comment: take it a step further, declare the variable a scope higher and check it in the while loop as well